# Javascript .click event working in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: javascript, function, firefox, click

I have this bit of code to hide/show a tray from the bottom of the page. It works great everywhere but Firefox. In devtools it doesn't show an event listener on .toTab -- until you refresh the page. After refreshing everything works fine.

```
$(function(){
   $('.toTab').click(function(event){
   var currentHeight = ($('#toOfferContainer').height()*(-1))+90;
     $(this).toggleClass('showOffers');
     $('.toOverlay').toggleClass('shown');
     if ($(this).hasClass('showOffers')) {
       $('#toOfferContainer').animate({bottom:'-2px'},500);
     } else {
       $('#toOfferContainer').animate({bottom:currentHeight},500);
     }
  });
});
```

Clicking on .toTab just doesn't register anything -- not even any messages in console.

Any tips on what I might need to adjust?

EDIT: Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="todaysOffers">
    <div class="toOverlay">
        <div id="toOfferContainer">
            <div class="toTab">
                <img src="image.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="toContent">
                <a href="/link" class="someLink">
                <img src="image2.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the HTML?

Comment: Sure, I just edited the post with the HTML. It's quite simple.

Comment: To be clear, the entire div is positioned off the page, and slid into place with animate({bottom...}).